# how can i pass a data from graphql to another page?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, client, apollo

hi I wanted to pass data from to another page using graphql and here is my code sample

```
const getListQuery=gql`
{
    storelist{
        id
      storeName
      storeLogoUrl
      deliveryType
      storeDescription
    }
  }`
```

I want to pass the id of the storelist to the following query as store id
..

```
const getListQuery = gql`
      {
       
    salesdepartments(storeid:"5ef5cd9114a4659138eb8e11")
    {
      name
      id
     
      departmentProducts{
       productname
       images
       id
       price
     }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What are you using to render your "pages"? Some form of app navigation/routing? Please update your question to include how you get to other pages within your application.

Comment: i use route to link pages ..i have have to pass these data on a button click

Comment: Can you update your question to include routing code, and how you link to pages?